# Use acm certificate for lightsail instance via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-lightsail, aws-certificate-manager

I have an ACM certificate already generate using terraform and used for an ECS load balancer. Now I have host a Wordpress website using Lightsail at the same domain, so I want reuse the same certficate public key but `aws_acm_certificate` doesn't expose it as output. So I found out I can get it using AWS CLI like:

```
aws acm get-certificate --certificate-arn {certificate:arn} --output text --query CertificateChain
```

I tried to pass the certificate to a `aws_lightsail_key_pair` but I am getting different errors. For example:

```
resource "null_resource" "write_acm_public_key" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "aws acm get-certificate --certificate-arn ${aws_acm_certificate.default.arn} --output text --query CertificateChain > ${path.module}/acm-public-key.cert"
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
  }

  depends_on = [aws_acm_certificate.default]
}

data "local_file" "acm_public_key" {
  filename = "${path.module}/acm-public-key.cert"

  depends_on = [null_resource.write_acm_public_key]
}

resource "aws_lightsail_key_pair" "key" {
  count      = var.wp_enable ? 1 : 0

  name       = "${local.resource_prefix}-key"
  public_key = data.local_file.acm_public_key.content

  depends_on = [aws_acm_certificate.default, null_resource.write_acm_public_key, data.local_file.acm_public_key]
}
```

Says

> No such file or directory

How can I reuse the same certificate?

Comment: What is the FULL error message?

Comment: Shouldn't the key used in Lightsail be an SSH key and not an ACM certificate?